# SQLAlchemy - Right way for models/methods in more files

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

In my project, based on Flask + SQLAlchemy I have more files for more models.

For example:

```
# file: models_users.py
user_roles_association = db.Table('user_roles_association',
                                      Column('role_id',
                                             db.Integer,
                                             db.ForeignKey('roles.id')),
                                      Column('user_id',
                                             db.Integer,
                                             db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
                                      )


class User(UserMixin, Model):

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    first_name = Column(db.String(40), nullable=True)
    last_name = Column(db.String(40), nullable=True)

    roles = db.relationship('Role',
                                secondary=user_roles_association,
                                backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'),
                                lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, **kwargs):
        db.Model.__init__(self,
                          first_name=first_name,
                          last_name=last_name,
                          **kwargs)

    def my_roles(user_id):
        user = User.query.get(user_id)
        return user.roles.order_by(Role.id).all()
```

Second file:

```
# file: models_cofig.py
class Role(UserMixin, Model):
__tablename__ = 'roles'

id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = Column(db.String(40), unique=True, nullable=False)

def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
    """Create instance."""
    db.Model.__init__(self,
                      name=name,
                      **kwargs)

def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.name)
```

Okay, and question: **What is a right way to make method, where I can use models from other model files?**

Dirty way:

```
  # file models_user.py
from apps.config import Role

class User(UserMixin, Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
...
...
    def my_roles(user_id):
        user = User.query.get(user_id)
        return user.roles.order_by(Role.id).all()
```

**Note: Model Role is in second file.**

And I need use right and clear way for custom methods across more models files.

Thanks for any answers.